# Why is my app not available to Galaxy Nexus users, even though it was in the past?

Tags: android

After a recent update I have gotten a number of users complaining that they are unable to download my application from the market since their device "galaxy nexus" is not compatible in the bar. I have a galaxy nexus myself and have tested the app on the device. These same users were able to use the previous version, and I have not made any changes in the manifest in the new update.

Is there anything I can do to make my application available to these users?

I do have a tablet and a phone build though the market filtering has been good in the past to send the phone build to phones and the tablet build to tablets based on reported screen density and OS version.

Comment: ive had this issue before. It happened to be a bug in the market =(

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just need to contact Google and hope for a response then.

Comment: Yeah also double check your manifest to make sure there isnt a mistake on filtering.

Comment: Take a look in what google maby changed about device specifics. just an example mdpi, hdpi.

Comment: I would ask what version of Android they're running. If they're running a hacked together version of Jelly Bean (4.1) like I am, that may be the cause. I've noticed some apps unavailable since I updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you register your app in Market, you have to choose different screen sizes.

Try putting "Support Screens" tag in manifest.

.